# Doctrine2 throwing an Exception in Symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am gettin an exeption as below:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 53: Error: Expected known function, got 'MONTH'
```

when trying to execute the following query using doctrine2 in symfony2:

```
SELECT e FROM EntityBundle:Employee e  WHERE MONTH(e.dateOfJoining) = 03 order by e.name
```

when i tried to execute the similar query as shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM employee e WHERE MONTH(e.date_of_joining) = 03;
```

it worked fine in phpmyadmin. So can anyone suggest how can i implement the same query doctrine2 with symfony2?

Answer (score 2):

Try reading this article about [registering functions with doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) but you should not be using it anyway.  It is very inefficient to filter based on an expression on a column.

You can achieve the same without the overhead by doing something like -

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employee e
WHERE e.dateOfJoining BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-31'
ORDER BY e.name
```

This query will be able to use any applicable index on the dateOfJoining column.

Comment: thanks nnichols, since i am not dealing with the whole date rather only with the extracted month from the mysql db, the **BETWEEN** trick won't work.

Comment: It can always be made to work. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with YEAR(). It is not implemented in Doctrine 2.

The solution is to install (via Composer) the plugin beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

```
> composer require beberlei/DoctrineExtensions "dev-master"
```

Don't forget to add the function you need in the config.yml. Something like:

```
> doctrine:
>     orm:
>         dql:
>             string_functions:
>                 MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
```